# Core data save object in thread with relation

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have a class `Store`, with method `fetchProducts` that working in background and save products from json data.

```
class Store: NSManagedObject {

       func fetchProducts(q: String) {
            ....
            let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {
                self.saveProduct(json_data)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

In this class i have a method `saveProduct` that checks if product exist, then this product should be update or create new:

```
func saveProduct(data:[String: String]) -> Bool {
        var product:Product
        var products = self.products.allObjects as! [Product]
        if (self.managedObjectContext == nil) {
            return false
        }

        if (data["storeName"] != nil) {
           products = products.filter{ $0.storeName == data["storeName"] }
    } else {
        return false
    }

        let privateContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .PrivateQueueConcurrencyType)
        privateContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = self.managedObjectContext!.persistentStoreCoordinator

        if (data["storeName"] != nil) {
            products = products.filter{ $0.storeName == data["storeName"] }
        } else {
            return false
        }
        if products.count > 0 {
            product = products.first!
        } else {
            if let productEntity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Product", inManagedObjectContext: privateContext) {
                product = Product(entity: productEntity, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: privateContext)
            } else {
                return false
            }
        }

        product.setValue(data["storeName"], forKey: "storeName")
        product.setValue(data["storeType"], forKey: "storeType")
        product.setValue(self, forKey: "shopItem")
        privateContext.performBlockAndWait {
            do {
                try privateContext.save()
            } catch {
                fatalError("Failure to save context: \(error)")
            }

        }

        return true
    }
```

But i get error for this line: `product.setValue(self, forKey: "shopItem")`

> Illegal attempt to establish a relationship between objects in
>   different contexts

How do i save fk field for product ?

Comment: Note that you should not set the `persistenStoreCoordinator` on the private context (deprecated). Instead, set the `parentContext`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run through `product = products.first!` then you're using an original product from the same context as 'self'. That context isn't the same as `privateContext` so your save doesn't actually persist the change.

If you run through `product = Product(entity:...` then you're using a new product in the `privateContext` which is different to the context of `self`.

What you should really be doing is either filtering on the current thread and using the `objectID` to lookup the match in the `privateContext`, or doing a filtered fetch on the `privateContext`. In this way you always have a product in the `privateContext`. You then need to use `self.objectID` to get `self` in the `privateContext` so you can update the relationship and save.

This is all required to maintain thread confinement.

Indeed, you should also be running this is `performBlock` (or the wait version) so the context can run the logic in its private queue.